# Why is my TextBox not binding?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

This is my code behind:

```
Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private _importPath As String

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ImportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(AppSettingsKeys.ImportFileDir)
        ImportPathBox.Text = ImportPath
    End Sub

    Public Property ImportPath As String
        Get
            Return _importPath
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _importPath = value
            OnMyPropertyChanged("ImportPath")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub OnMyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the relevant portion of my markup, for `MainWindow`:

```
<TextBox Name="ImportPathBox" Text="{Binding Path=ImportPath}" Margin="110, 5, 30, 5"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Yet despite setting `ImportPath` a value, which it retains, `ImportPathBox` remains blank, and any changed made to her are not conveyed back to `ImportPath`. This seems like trivial data binding, but my WPF has become a bit rusty.

Comment: why your tag is **C#**?

Comment: Oops, I'm used to C#, and SO suggested it, and I blindly accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you set `DataContext` for you binding but assuming that is done problem is here

```
ImportPathBox.Text = ImportPath
```

by doing that you effectively force manual value onto your `TextBox`. You don't need this line. If you don't set `DataContext` anywhere then you'll need something like

```
Me.DataContext = Me
```

in your constructor

Comment: I thought DataContect was implicitly set, especially when the bound variable is directly in the main window. The `ImportPathBox.Text = ImportPath` was a overlooked attempt at doing without data binding.

Answer (score 2):

As staed by dkozl you must set datacontext of yor view. I would reccomend using MVVM and a ViewModelLocator such as the one provided by Galasoft MVVM Ligtht, avaliable through nuget... Or you can cut corners and declare it either in the ctor or in xaml.

or ctor of the view as stated earlierd:
    Me.DataContext = this; // please use a vm instead

If you want your textbox to post back to the vm property you need twoway binding

```
<TextBox Name="ImportPathBox" Text="{Binding Path=ImportPath, Mode=TwoWay}".../>
```

Note that the default UpdateSourceTrigger is set to LostFocus, this means that your VM's propery will only be updated from gui when the tb looses focus. If you set it to PropertyChanged it will update each time the the user edits the tb.

Cheers